# Add listitems to top while maintaining position

Tags: android, twitter, arraylist, custom-adapter

I am trying to add new Listview items to the top while at the same time keeping that same position as new items are added. I've tried using this.

```
TweetList getItem(int position) {
        return this.tweetList.get(tweetList.getSize() - 1 - position);
    }
```

but it always changes the top position to 0. How can I add items to the top without hindering the position of the item?

```
public class TweetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tweet,twitterUser,twitterMention;
    ImageView profile_picture,tweet_picture;
    View padding;
    TweetList tweetMessageObj;
    ViewHolder holder = null;


    public List<TweetList> tweetList = new ArrayList<TweetList>();


    public void add(TweetList object) {
        tweetList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    public TweetArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.tweetList.size();
    }

    public TweetList getItem(int position) {
        return this.tweetList.get(position);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
            tweetMessageObj = getItem(position);

            if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.twitterUser = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            holder.tweet = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.display_tweet);
            holder.twitterMention = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.display_twitter_mentionname);
            holder.profile_picture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
            holder.tweet_picture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.tweet_image);
            holder.padding = (View)row.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            holder.favorite = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);
            holder.retweet = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.retweet_button);
            holder.reply = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.reply_button);
            holder.favorite.setTag(holder);

             row.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            SpannableString hashtag = new SpannableString(tweetMessageObj.tweet);
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
            Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
            while (matcher.find())
            {
                hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
                hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                         String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                        }
                },matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
            }
            while (matcher2.find())
            { hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
                hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                         String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                        }
                },matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
            }
            holder.tweet.setText(hashtag, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            holder.tweet.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            holder.tweet.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            if(tweetMessageObj.tweet.isEmpty()){
                holder.tweet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/light.ttf");
            holder.tweet.setTypeface(tf);
            Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/bold.ttf");
            holder.twitterUser.setText(tweetMessageObj.twittername);
            holder.twitterUser.setTypeface(tf2);
            holder.twitterMention.setText("@" + tweetMessageObj.mentionname);

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(tweetMessageObj.pictureURL).into(holder.profile_picture);
            if(tweetMessageObj.tweetPictureUrl != null){
                holder.tweet_picture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.padding.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(tweetMessageObj.tweetPictureUrl).into(holder.tweet_picture);
            }else{
                holder.tweet_picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.padding.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        return row;
    }
```

Edit:

```
public class TweetArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tweet,twitterUser,twitterMention;
    ImageView profile_picture,tweet_picture;
    View padding;
    TweetList tweetMessageObj;
    ViewHolder holder = null;


    public List<TweetList> tweetList = new ArrayList<TweetList>();


    int index = 0;

    public void add(TweetList object) {
            tweetList.add(index, object);
            index++;
        }

    public TweetArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.tweetList.size();
    }

    public TweetList getItem(int position) {
        return tweetList.get(position);
    } 

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
            tweetMessageObj = getItem(position);

            if(convertView == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tweet_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.twitterUser = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            holder.tweet = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.display_tweet);
            holder.twitterMention = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.display_twitter_mentionname);
            holder.profile_picture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
            holder.tweet_picture = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.tweet_image);
            holder.padding = (View)row.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            holder.favorite = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);
            holder.retweet = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.retweet_button);
            holder.reply = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.reply_button);
            holder.favorite.setTag(holder);

             row.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            SpannableString hashtag = new SpannableString(tweetMessageObj.tweet);
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
            Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtag);
            while (matcher.find())
            {
                hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
                hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                         String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                        }
                },matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
            }
            while (matcher2.find())
            { hashtag.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(79, 120, 216)), matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
                hashtag.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View widget) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        TextView tv = (TextView)widget;
                         String tags = tv.getText().subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tags,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
                           ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
                        }
                },matcher2.start(), matcher2.end(), 0);
            }
            holder.tweet.setText(hashtag, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            holder.tweet.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            holder.tweet.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            if(tweetMessageObj.tweet.isEmpty()){
                holder.tweet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/light.ttf");
            holder.tweet.setTypeface(tf);
            Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/bold.ttf");
            holder.twitterUser.setText(tweetMessageObj.twittername);
            holder.twitterUser.setTypeface(tf2);
            holder.twitterMention.setText("@" + tweetMessageObj.mentionname);

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(tweetMessageObj.pictureURL).into(holder.profile_picture);
            if(tweetMessageObj.tweetPictureUrl != null){
                holder.tweet_picture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.padding.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(tweetMessageObj.tweetPictureUrl).into(holder.tweet_picture);
            }else{
                holder.tweet_picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.padding.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused with your question. Are you saying the the list view always scrolls to the top when you add new items? or are you trying to maintain the same index of the items when you add new ones?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do Ryan.

Comment: Which one? haha. Maintain the scroll position when adding items?

Comment: lol,sorry. Maintain the index of the items as i add new ones. Basically When i add a new item I want it to appear on the top,but I want the index to remain the same. Say if I add 1 item to the list,by selection that item is going to be 0. When I used return this.tweetList.get(tweetList.getSize() - 1 - position); as I added more to the listview,the new one was at position 0;

Comment: So if I have this right, you want to be able to add an item to your list, but have it appear at an index that is different than its index in its list data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to get at... An easier way to do this would be to simply add your new items at a specific index. Try this instead:

```
public void add(TweetList object, int index) {
        tweetList.add(index, object);
        super.add(index, object);
    }
```

I think if you do this, you wont have to do all the extra work in your `getItem()` method. That could also be changed to:

```
TweetList getItem(int position) {
        return tweetList.get(position);
    }
```

If your List is already in the order that you would like it to appear in your ListView, then you have less work to do and it will be less prone to errors. Hopefully I understand correctly, and hopefully this helps!

EDIT:

Keep a variable that hold the index of where the next item should be added..

```
    private int index = 0;

    public void add(TweetList object) {
            tweetList.add(index, object);
            index++;
        }
```

Doing this will add the first new item to the top of the list, and any subsequent items will be added behind the most recently added new item.

Comment: I think I got it,I removed the index parameter in super.

Comment: Hmm,it's adding to the top,but the position isn't changing. super.add won't let me add the index though,so I'm gonna assume that's the issue.

Comment: You mean, the List View position is not changing?

Comment: And I'd get rid of the super call altogether unless you have a specific need for it.

Comment: Okay I think i can explain it better. The items that are adding to the top are always becoming position 0. I want it to be the first list item is 0,the next item added to the top will be 1,the next item after that will be 2,the next will be 3 and so forth.

Comment: Assuming that you are changing this content dynamically, you could keep a local variable that holds the index where the next item should be added. The difficulty that you are running into is that there is already content in the adapter, so by keeping an index, adding the new items at the index location, and incrementing the index everytime you add an item, you can achieve what you want. I'll make an edit to show you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62684/discussion-between-user1543533-and-ryanm).

Answer (score 0):

you have to manipulate the listview

```
// before adding new elements
int currentPosition = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View child = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = child == null ? 0 : child.getTop();
//TODO add new elements
mList.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + numberOfNewElements, top);
```